# how can get ng-model value within ng-repeat on directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I want's to get the value of ng-model within the the ng-repeat on my own directive and use the value of that ng-model in the directive for a fuction.

here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MaI8DOtdc4yucXgNo05p?p=preview) to see code in action :

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/MaI8DOtdc4yucXgNo05p?p=preview
```

here is my directive code :

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('barname.rtEditor', [])
    .directive('rtEditor', rtEditor);

  function rtEditor() {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'rt-ht.html',
      compile: compile
    };

    function compile() {

      return {
        post: function(scope, element, attrs) {

          scope.com = {

            inp: [{
              name: 'video',
              model: scope.vimodel,
              command: 'insertHTML',
              modelcommand: scope.vimodel
            }, {
              name: 'pic',
              model: scope.pimodel,
              command: 'insertImage',
              modelcommand: scope.pimodel
            }, {
              name: 'link',
              model: scope.linkmodel,
              command: 'createLink',
              modelcommand: scope.linkmodel
            }]

          };

          scope.$watch('vimodel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log('vim model watch :-> ', newValue);
          });

          scope.$watch('texmodel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log('text model watch :-> ', newValue);
          });

          scope.execIn = function(cmd, val) {

            console.log('cmd val :->', cmd + ' | ' + val);

            scope.vimodel = '';
            scope.texmodel = '';

          };
        }
      };

    }
  }
})();
```

and here is the html code :

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="inp in com.inp" id="{{inp.name}}">
    <label>{{inp.name}} :</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="inp.model" />
    <span ng-click="execIn(inp.command, inp.modelcommand)">doIt!</span>
  </div>

  <br>
  <hr>
  <br>

  <div>
    <label>widout ng repeat:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="texmodel" />
    <span ng-click="execIn('textIn', texmodel)">doIt!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can easily get the value of the ng-model without ng-repeat

Comment: `ng-model="inp.model[0]"` did not work

Comment: It has to be inp[0].model